# How to add a color transitions in CSS and HTML like the one in the login area of the Instagram app?

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, instagram

I wanted to add the rainbow-y color change and transition to the background of a site I'm making. I can't seem to get it to work and googling has not helped a lot. Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#hi {
  background: rgb(250, 100, 100);
  border: 0;
  transition: background 2s ease-out;
}
#hi:hover {
  /*background: rgb(200, 100, 250);*/
  background: rgb(100, 100, 250);
}
```

```html
<button id="hi">.............
  <br>.............
  <br>.............</button>
```

So in the be above code, I just make a button with a bunch of periods which make up a box. Then in the CSS, you should just do the regular *"add the transition stuff"*, but then you should also add `ease-out` at the end, which gives a little *pull* at certain parts of the transition. and in the `:hover`section, you can choose any color you want.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use the `@keyframe animation` tool in css.
Example:

```
.element {
  animation: pulse 5s infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    background-color: #001F3F;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #FF4136;
  }
}
```

Comment: okay, I will implement it and report back. The ".element" will be the name of the element on which the animation is to be applied, right? sorry, but I'm new to css